# Check if a file is a specific type in C

Tags: c, linux, directory, iteration, header-files

I'm writing my first C program, though I come from a C++ background.

I need to iterate through a directory of files and check to see if the file is a header file, and then return the count.

My code is as follows, it's pretty rudimentary I think:

```
static int CountHeaders( const char* dirname ) {

    int header_count = 0;
    DIR* dir_ptr;
    struct dirent* entry;

    dir_ptr = opendir( dirname );

    while( ( entry = readdir( dir_ptr ) ) )
    {
        if ( entry->d_type == DT_REG )
        {
            //second if statement to verify the file is a header file should be???
            ++header_count;
        }
    }

    closedir( dir_ptr );

    return header_count;
}
```

What would be a good if statement to check to see if the file is a header?

Comment: You can't tell for sure if a file is a header file or not, neither when looking at the extension nor via the file's content.

Answer (score 3):

Simply check if the file extension is `.h`, something like:

```
const char *ext = strrchr (entry->d_name, '.');     
if ((ext != NULL) && (!strcmp (ext+1, "h"))) {
     // header file
}
```

Ofcourse, note that this assumes all your header files have an `.h` extension, which may or may not be true, the C standard does not mandate that header files must have an `.h` extension.

Comment: That'll work, but I'd be checking `ext` agianst the NULL pointer before doing that `strcmp`. Otherwise the file `boom_crash_segv` is going to cause you some trouble :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Indeed, the `NULL` pointer check after `strrchr()` is a **must** :)

Comment: Added the NULL check, please validate and either confirm or abuse :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Thanks.Im at work and for some reason the connection becomes too slow for an edit but not for a new post.strange..

Answer (score 2):

Each `dirent` structure has a `d_name` containing the name of the file, so I'd be looking to see if that followed some pattern, like ending in `.h` or `.hpp`.

That would be code along the lines of:

```
int len = strlen (entry->d_name);
if ((len >= 2) && strcmp (&(entry->d_name[len - 2]), ".h") == 0))
    header_count++;
if ((len >= 4) && strcmp (&(entry->d_name[len - 4]), ".hpp") == 0))
    header_count++;
```

Of course, that won't catch truly evil people from calling their executables `ha_ha_fooled_you.hpp` but thanfkfully they're in the minority.

You may even want to consider an `endsWith()` function to make your life easier:

```
int endsWith (char *str, char *end) {
    size_t slen = strlen (str);
    size_t elen = strlen (end);
    if (slen < elen)
        return 0;
    return (strcmp (&(str[slen-elen]), end) == 0);
}
:
if (endsWith (entry->d_name, ".h"))   header_count++;
if (endsWith (entry->d_name, ".hpp")) header_count++;
```

Comment: At this point you'd probably want to declare a `NULL` terminated array with extensions to compare with, something like: `{ ".h", ".hpp", NULL }`

Comment: Yes, there's no end to the complexity you could add but I'd better stop here, lest my answer become an essay :-)

Comment: @tadman: The Q is tagged `c` so it *can be assumed* that the header wont be named `.hpp`.

Comment: Not _necessarily_ so, the OP might want to _write_ the code in C but search for other headers. I write `awk` and `Perl` scripts to process all sorts of non-awk/Perl files (including headers). In any case, the OP can plug in (or remove) whatever values they want.

Comment: I interpreted it as the *implementation* is in C, but the files themselves might be anything. Headers today, movie files tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

There are some much better methods than checking the file extension.

Wikipedia has a good article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Identifying_file_type) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). The latter idea is called the magic number database which essentially means that if a file contains blah sequence then it is the matching type listed in the database. Sometimes the number has restrictions on locations and sometimes it doesnt. This method IMO is more accurate albeit slower than file extension detection.

But then again, for something as simple as checking to see if its a header, this may be a bit of overkill XD

Comment: Is there a C way of doing this? What libraries would be needed to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the last few characters are one of the header-file extensions, .h, .hpp, etc. Use the `dirent` struct's `d_name` for the name of the file.

Or, you could run the 'file' command and parse its result.

Comment: Using an external command is not very effective if there are many files, and checking for extension doesn't work for example for the C++ standard library header files. But personally I would just check for extension anyway, starting with `".h"` before testing for other common header-file extensions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I agree with you on the external command. The `file` command can tell you it is C code, not necessarily a header, so it is quite effective, just not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to check the file extension. Using [dirent](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dirent.h.html), you would want to look at `d_name`.

Answer (score 0):

That's up to you.

The easiest way is to just look at the filename (d_name), and check whether it ends with something like ".h" or ".hpp" or whatever.

Opening the file and actually reading it to see if it's valid c/c++, on the other hand, will be A LOT more complex... you could run it through a compiler, but not every header works on its own, so that test will give you a lot of false negatives.